# mocha returns "callback is not a function" for async calls

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, gulp, mocha.js, babeljs

i'm trying to use nodejs (es6 + babel) along with mocha.

Here is the Base class i'm testing :

```js
import cheerio from 'cheerio';
import ResourceRequest from './ResourceRequest';

export default class HtmlValueParser {

  constructor(url, headers) {
    this.rr = new ResourceRequest(url, headers);
    this.body = null;
    this.$ = null;
  }

  getValue(query) {
    if (!query) {
      return;
    }
    if (this.$ === null){
      this.$ = cheerio.load(this.body);
      return 'toto';
    }else {
      return 'titi';
    }
  }

  getAValue(query, callback) {
    if (this.body === null) {
      this.rr.getResource((error, response, body) => {
        this.body = body;
        let val = this.getValue(query);
        callback(null, val);
      });
    }else {
      process.nextTick(callback(null, this.getValue(query)));
    }
  }
}
```

I'm just downloading an HTML ressource and then willing to do a css query to get a specific value into it.
I  have put in place a basic caching of the content downloaded so i can query it with the getAValue multiple time and using nextTick allows me to keep the function consistently asynchronous.

The ResourceRequest Object is just a simple abstraction of the request module :

```js
import request from 'request';

export default class ResourceRequest {

  constructor(url, headers){
    this.options = {
      url: url,
      headers: headers
    };
  }

  getResource(callback) {
    request(this.options, callback);
  }

}
```

This all works flawlessly in my index.js, but using mocha (along with Istanbul for coverage) to test it (once without caching, next to see if caching is used), i get the following error :

> TypeError in plugin 'gulp-mocha' Message:
>       callback is not a function Details:
>       domain: [object Object]
>       domainThrown: true Stack: TypeError: callback is not a function
>       at doNTCallback0 (node.js:407:9)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:377:13)

here is my testfile :

```js
import assert from 'assert';
import HtmlValueParser from '../lib/HtmlValueParser';

var url = 'http://google.fr';
var headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36'
};

describe('HTMLValueParser', function() {
  var hvp = new HtmlValueParser(url, headers);
  describe('Empty Cache', function() {
    it('should not use cache', function(done) {
      hvp.getAValue({}, function(error, value) {
        assert.equal(value, 'toto', 'value should be toto');
        done();
      });
    });
  });
  describe('Cache Enabled', function() {
    it('should use cache', function(done) {
      hvp.getAValue({}, function(error, value) {
        assert.equal(value, 'titi', 'value should be titi');
        done();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

the error happens after the second "it" test.

Not sure if this me using it wrongly or if this is a bug in gulp-mocha or ... well i don't know !

Anyway thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I finally found out i was wrongly using process.nextTick();
I had written process.nextTick(callback(null, this.getValue(query)));
instead of 
process.nextTick(() => {
        callback(null, this.getValue(query));
      });